# Recuperar entero de localStorage JS en Chrome

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Estoy guardando un `localStorage` de la siguiente manera y lo pinto en un `<p>`;

```
var punt1=document.getElementById("puntJ1");
var punt2=document.getElementById("puntJ2");

function pintarPuntosJugadores(){
if(localStorage.getItem("jugador1")==null){
    localStorage.setItem("jugador1","0");
    localStorage.setItem("jugador2","0");
}
punt1.textContent=localStorage.getItem("jugador1");
punt2.textContent=localStorage.getItem("jugador2");   
}
```

El resultado cuando cargo la página es 0, el problema viene cuando quiero aumentar ese 0 a un 1 luego 2 etc... según gane un jugador u otro.

```
function Ganador(){

let jugador="";
if(turno){
    jugador="jugador1";
}else{
    jugador="jugador2";
}
alert(jugador+" Ha ganado");
let puntJugAct=localStorage.getItem(jugador);
//let result=parseInt(puntJugAct) +1;
console.log(typeof(puntJugAct));
console.log(parseInt(puntJugAct)  + 1);

localStorage.setItem(jugador,puntJugAct);
pintarPuntosJugadores();

}
```

El problema es que el tipo recuperado es `object`y si hago `console.log(parseInt(puntJugAct)  + 1);` el resultado que me arroja es `NAN`

Mientras que haciendo `console.log(puntJugAct  + 1);`,
me concatena el `string` recuperado del `localStorage` (0) con el 1 que le quiero sumar, arrojando un resultado como: 01

¿Como podría transformar ese valor recuperado a `int` para operar con el?

Comment: Has probado a añadir el integer directamente al localStorage? 
 Sería algo así: localStorage.setItem("jugador1",0);

Comment: Si tambien lo probré, sin exito

Comment: No puede ser eso, `typeof(puntJugAct)` devuelve un *string* no un objeto. Con el código que has puesto hace bien la suma, debes tener alguna otra cosa en tu programa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trate de hacer tu mismo código y me daba el mismo error, y vi que estaba dando ese NaN porque cuando tratabas de sumar el valor contenido en `localStorage.getItem(jugador)` no tenia ningún valor ni siquiera 0, por eso inicialice ese localstorage con 0 y luego si pude sumarlo con éxito, debería de quedar así:

```
var punt1=document.getElementById("puntJ1");
var punt2=document.getElementById("puntJ2");
localStorage.setItem("jugador1","0");
localStorage.setItem("jugador2","0");
```

y luego si puedes sumar así:

```
let puntJugAct = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(jugador)) + 1;
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/dmolina101/2cvtm518/6/).

también es vez de inicializarlos en 0 puede colocar una condición así:

```
isNaN(parseInt(localStorage.getItem(jugador)))
```

Con esto defines que si el valor que esta en esa **localstorage** es un **NaN** lo seteas a 0, quedando así:

```
let puntJugAct =  (isNaN(parseInt(localStorage.getItem(jugador)))) ? 0 : parseInt(localStorage.getItem(jugador));
```

Espero te sirva.